# How can I make a div 80% the size of the page?

Tags: css, html

I'd like to make a page container div have a top margin of 10% and bottom margin of 10%. How can I make the div take the remaining 80% of the page, all the time ( no matter if it has content or not )?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div { 
                position: absolute;
                height: 80%; 
                width: 80%; 
                top: 10%; 
                left: 10%; 
                background-color: #FFCC00; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            This should prove my point.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
CSS
---
.container {
   margin-top:10%;
   margin-bottom:10%;
   height:80%;
}

<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. It does add a margin to the top of the div, but the height is still as required to fit the content and nothing more (at least in Firefox, HTML5 mode).

Comment: @tdammers Good additions, I see you added position, width, top and left. @Geo Ensure you test in all browsers. You might stumble upon minor differences. Best

Comment: Width and left are actually a bonus, doing the same on the X axis. `position: absolute` is what does the trick.