# how to make UI(user interface) responsive for all width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I make one UI after googling .But my UI is not responsive it not look good when I increase the window size or decrease the window size/.

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/X8HV9/1/show/
I have only two issues

1. "up level" button it look good when window size is more (full screen).When I decrease the size of window it changes it position.But next and previous button look good.
2. When you click "add" button it show pop up screen when screen size is more(full screen).but it hide when screen is smaller.

can I give width in %?

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">

    <div class="main_cont">

        <div class="cb"></div>

        <section>

            <div class="contentbox">
                <div class="actionbar">
                    <a href="#" class="home" id="home_h"></a><a href="#" class="previous" id="previous_h"><i
                    class="iconprev"></i>Previous</a><a href="#" class="next" id="next_h"><i
                    class="iconnext"></i>Next</a>
                    <a style="position: relative;top: 6px;left: 89px;cursor: pointer;" id="oneLevelUp">Up level ^</a>
                    <div class="cb"></div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </section>

        <footer id="firstPageFooter">
            <button class="addtestbtn" id="addTestCase" data-theme="a" style="color: #ffffff!important;">Add Test Case</button>

        </footer>


        <div data-role="popup" id="testCaseId" data-theme="b" data-arrow="b">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="testCaseIDValue">Test Case ID:</label>
                <input type="text" name="testCaseIDValue" id="testCaseIDValue" value=""  class="inputTextTestCase"/>
            </div>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" id="donePopUp">Done</a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: @RPM UI yes UI .Need to improve UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use % scaling with width,height,top,left,margins

for example in your css:

```
#next_h{
   position:absolute;
   width:10%;
}
```

this will set width to 10% of window's width

if you want to scale when window is below certain width,

you can use javascript:

```
if($(window).outerWidth() < 500){
  $('#next_h).css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'width':'80%',
    'height':'10px'
  });
}
```

something like this.

you might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317924/how-can-i-make-a-div-80-the-size-of-the-page) post too

Comment: can you change some fiddle .so that I will better understan

Comment: just change for button .Next I will do next myseft

Comment: i posted some code. this should work on html too. :)